# sum the column values(group_by) keeping NA values and not replacing with zero in R

Tags: r

I am trying to sum the column values group by another column, I need to keep NA values i should not replace the values with zero because based on the sum I have to give Rank if sum is NA rank should be empty.

below is example to under stand the problem

column1   column2   column3

a        gb          10

b        gb          NA

c        gb          NA

d        gb          4

e        Hs          81

b        Hs          NA

c        Hs          2

a        Rd          NA

x        Rd          NA

z        Rd          NA

I have to sum column3 values group by column2 and while doing sum I should not take NA values into consideration and sum other values for that group I should not remove or replace the NA values with zero. based on this sum I have to give rank if the sum is NA(refer group Rd) there will be no Rank for that. I can replace the NA values with zero but I have to give rank after sum, if sum is NA rank will be empty(in case of group Rd from the above data). and for group gb the sum value is 14 and group Hs sum value is 83 and group Rd sum value is NA in this case there will be no rank for the group.

below is the code snippet i tried

df %>% group_by_at(column2) %>%
    summarise(sum = sum(column3, na.rm = TRUE))

above code sum the values by replacing all NA with zero but I don't want to replace. I need NA in giving rank. can you please provide any solution fro this.

expected output:

column2      column3    rank

gb            14         2

Hs            83         1

Rd            NA         No Rank

Comment: expected output should be something like below

column2 column3 rank

gb 14 2

Hs 83 1

Rd NA No Rank

Comment: can you please check my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `rank` with `na.last = "keep"` to give `rank` as `NA`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(column2) %>% 
  summarise(column3 = if(all(is.na(column3))) NA else 
                         sum(column3, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(rank = rank(-column3, na.last = "keep"))

#  column2 column3  rank
#  <fct>     <int> <dbl>
#1 gb           14     2
#2 Hs           83     1
#3 Rd           NA    NA
```

Comment: there will be zero's also in column3 data along with NA

Comment: @Hmm okay. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sum_` from `hablar` which would return `NA` if all the values are `NA` and then use `dense_rank`

```
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)
df %>% 
  group_by(column2) %>% 
  summarise(column3 = sum_(column3))  %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(-column3))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  column2 column3  rank
#  <chr>     <int> <int>
#1 gb           14     2
#2 Hs           83     1
#3 Rd           NA    NA
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(column3 = sum_(column3)), column2][, 
       rank := frank(-column3, na.last = 'keep')][]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(column1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "b", "c", 
"a", "x", "z"), column2 = c("gb", "gb", "gb", "gb", "Hs", "Hs", 
"Hs", "Rd", "Rd", "Rd"), column3 = c(10L, NA, NA, 4L, 81L, NA, 
2L, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
within(aggregate(column3~column2, df, FUN = function(x){
    ifelse(all(is.na(x)), NA_integer_, sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))}, 
    na.action = na.pass), {rank = ifelse(is.na(column3), NA_integer_,
                                         rank(-column3))})
```